# System freezes: PCIe bus error

Tags: freeze, pcie

I've searched for similar errors here but couldn't find the same.

So, I have a dual boot (Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.40). I never use Windows, it's just a backup system. It's been like this on this new laptop for over one year when Ubuntu started freezing shortly after the programs stopped responding. The console screen shows this PCIe bus error you can see in the image linked, repeatedly spamming.

[image: ubuntu console showing error after freezing]

I reinstalled Ubuntu, but the error persists. I tried to install Pop OS, but it gave me the same error before the installation. No luck with Debian either, they froze after suspending when idle.

Windows 11 also works weirdly, though it doesn't freeze for good like Ubuntu, it freezes for many seconds and often, then resumes. Or some programs stop working and resume.

I also noticed that when I run a Linux distro from a flash drive, I get no errors, it works fine, it seems.

I believe it's a hardware issue, as even Windows shows similar problems, but I wonder what it could be. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like failing hardware.  If the system runs long enough you can use lspci to see which device is failing.  You can see from the log that it is PCI ID e0:1d.0  (bus e0, device 1d, function 0), but lspci will give you a human readable name.

```
lspci -s e0:1d.0 -v
```

If you are lucky it will be something replaceable like the M.2 NVMe SSD (which the Asus X513EA does have).